# How to Set Rich Text in Asana Project Description via API

Tags: asana

Is there a way to include rich text when setting the project description via the API? I can set the description via the notes attribute, but any HTML renders as plain text. I have also tried using html_text.

Sample request:

```
{
"data": {
    "name": "Test project",
    "notes": "<strong>Sample project description</strong>",
    "html_text": "<strong>Sample project description</strong>",
    "team": <team_number>,
    "workspace": <workspace_id>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you're on the right track. However, there are a couple issues:

- The description of the project is `notes` (see https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/projects), so the rich text field would be `html_notes`.
- Projects don't currently support `html_notes` in the API. Though that's likely to change in future, I'm afraid I can't really guess at when that's likely to happen - there's a lot on our roadmap.
- `html_text` and `html_notes` are not officially supported fields yet, and the behavior of them is likely to change. If you want to take advantage right now, be aware that it's *very* finicky about the format of the HTML.