# Can I send an HTML tags like <b> or <strong> in a POST request, so that my text is bold once it gets to Asana?

Tags: html, asana, asana-api

I'm creating a Task using a POST HTTP request, it's working fine and my task is being created on Asana.
here's an example of the task I'm sending

```
var task = {
  data: {
    assignee: "me",
    workspace: "1234567", 
    projects: "9876543",
    parent: null,
    notes:`Full Name: ${myData.fullName}
           First Name: ${myData.firstName}
           City: ${myData.city}`
  }
 }
```

Once my task gets created in Asana, I would like the notes to be displayed like this, with part of the string bold:

**Full Name**: John Doe

**First Name**: John

**City**: San Francisco

My unsuccessful attempt was like this:

```
var task = {
  data: {
    assignee: "me",
    workspace: "1234567", 
    projects: "9876543",
    parent: null,
    notes:`<b>Full Name:</b> ${myData.fullName}
           <b>First Name:</b> ${myData.firstName}
           <b>City:</b> ${myData.city}`
  }
}
```

And I ended up getting this as a result as a note in Asana:

```
<b>Full Name</b> John Doe

<b>First Name:</b> John

<b>City:</b> San Francisco
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two changes in your request in order to get your desired text formatting:

1. Use `html_notes` instead of `notes`. The `notes` field is treated as a literal, which is why you are seeing raw HTML instead of bolded text in Asana.
2. Use the `<strong>` tag instead of `<b>` to bold the text.

Comment: I still get the same result when I use `html_notes`. I still get `<p>some text </p>` ?

Comment: [See this previous question on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962213/how-to-set-rich-text-in-asana-project-description-via-api).  I will also investigate further.