# How to create a task in asana with bold description?

Tags: asana, asana-api

I am able to create Project / task /  attachment fine with Asana API with PHP.
Is there a way to create **Bold** for *Emphasis* description for task / project ?
I could not find that in Asana API.
Can someone point me to right direction?

Comment: See previous question with answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43106229/can-i-send-an-html-tags-like-b-or-strong-in-a-post-request-so-that-my-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that if you send in **html_notes** instead of **notes** you will be able to use SOME html tags. The html tags that is valid is not documented, so you will have to test to find working tags.

```
"html_notes": "<strong>This will be bold in Asana</strong>"
```

I used the following with success when creating a task within a Workspace and a project. Note that this is using WebRequest in a ASP.NET WebApi (C#). But the Json string should work just fine with your project :)

**IMPORTANT:** Do not encode the html before POST.

```
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks");
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer <PERSONAL_TOKEN>"); 
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

            string json = "{\"data\": {\"workspace\": \"123456789\",\"html_notes\": \"<strong>" + question.Message + "</strong>\",\"name\": \"" + Username + "\",\"projects\": \"123456789\"}}";

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                sw.Write(json);
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks..!
I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: That worked great.!
Were you able to create to new line (\n or <br>) to notes ?

Comment: I was able to find the newline..!
You need to send info with Literal new line.!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way using ASANA API's use this..

```
URL : https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks 
Method : POST
HEADER : Authorization:Bearer <your token>
         Content-Type:application/json
         Accept:application/json

Body : 
{
  "data": {
    "approval_status": "pending",
    "assignee": "1111----572318",
    "assignee_status": "upcoming",
    "due_on": "2019-09-15",
    "followers": [
      "31441----023","1617----554125"
    ],
    "html_notes": "<body>Looking how can i create task under a <strong>project</strong></body>",
    "name": "Task created form Postman - 3",
    "workspace": "11288-----8660",
    "projects":["1185----23561"]
  }
}
```

Sample
[image]